# Auto relacionamento doctrine

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine

Estou utilizando o Doctrine, e agora me surgiu o seguinte problema.

Estou realizando um cadastro de menus do sistema, onde o mesmo pode ter vários "filhos" e seus "filhos" também podem ter "filhos", e assim sucessivamente.

Como vou realizar esse auto-relacionamento com o doctrine?

Eu já realizei o mapeamento na classe Menu com os *annotations*, mas não consegui entender como vou fazer esse mapeamento na consulta, para que quando realizar a busca o objeto menu já venha preenchido com todos os itens corretamente.

Abaixo segue o mapeamento que realizei na classe Menu:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_Menu")
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue("SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="sq_Menu")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Menu", inversedBy="menuFilho")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idMenuPai", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $menuPai;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Menu", mappedBy="menuPai")
     */
    private $menuFilho;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titulo;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80)
     */
    private $descricao;

    /* 
     * Construtor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->menuFilho = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa fazer é criar um **Relacionamento One-To-Many Self-Referencing**.

Leia essa seção na documentação do Doctrine:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Basicamente, você vai usar uma única tabela para construir a árvore do seu menu, e as linhas dos nós filhos se relacionarão com seus respectivo nós pais por meio da mesma tabela.

Além disso, existe uma extensão muito interessante para o Doctrine, chamada [Tree](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md). Com essa extensão é possível construir estruturas semelhantes a árvores no seu banco de dados (por exemplo, seu caso de categorias e sub-categorias) e ainda renderizar um HTML em cima dessa estrutura. Veja se lhe serve.

Comment: Então Rodrigo eu já li esse artigo e fiz o auto-relacionamento da forma como eles explicaram, mas ainda não entendi como vou construir a minha query para retornar os dados. Se você tiver um exemplo aí e puder me passar eu te agradeço.

Comment: Editei a resposta citando uma extensão para o Doctrine para criar estruturas semelhantes ao que você precisa. Uso aqui para o mesmo propósito. Veja se lhe serve :)